# Date selection with only one dropdown

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select, drop-down-menu

I have a model articles with created_at

In my index view I want the user to be able to select all articles created in "October 2010, November 2010, December 2010, etc." with only one select dropdown.

Has anyone done this before?

Comment: Shouldn't this be fairly trivial in any given language? Group articles by month + year, order by date, populate dropdown. Where exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my controller I did:

```
@startdates = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_rows("SELECT DISTINCT MONTH(start_date), YEAR(start_date) FROM schedules WHERE event_id IN (#{@events.map{|n| n.id}.join(',')}) ORDER BY start_date ASC;")
```

and in my view:

```
<%= select(:event, :startdate, @startdates.map{|s| ["#{t("date.month_names")[s[0].to_i]} #{s[1]}", "#{s[1]}-#{s[0]}"]}, {:selected => @startdate.to_s, :include_blank => "All"}) %>
```

Answer (score 3):

Rails 3 (MySQL)

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...code here...
  def self.article_months
    group_by_clause = "to_char(created_at,'<your date format>')"
    Article.group(group_by_clause).select("#{group_by_clause} as month, count(*) as count").order(created_at desc).all
  end
  ...code here...
end
```

In your view, use select_tag or collection_select or something and render the collection above.

Comment: I'm running Rails 2.3.8 - I tried:
  def self.article_months
    group_by_clause = "DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%M %Y')"
    Article.find(:all, :group => group_by_clause, :select => "#{group_by_clause} as month", :order => "created_at ASC")
  end
In my view I used:
<%= select(:article, :created_at, Article.article_months %> but Article.article_months does not show the months, although the sql query gives me the right result.

Comment: So if your model method is working fine and returning the desired data. You just need to have a look at the view helpers to ensure that the correct parameters are being provided. Not sure you can use just select, perhaps it is select_tag (depends on if you are using form_for or form_tag). Have a look at some form related helpers. Let me know if you need more help.